# Custom user function without using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Is it possible to create a custom user function in Excel without using VBA?
My problem is I have a long string of standard excel functions strung together to make one very long function.
This function is used across 25 different worksheets in my workbook.  If I need to make changes to it I would like to do so in only one place and have the changes propagated across all the sheets automatically.

For example, a simple and trivial case would be to add one to the result of SUM(), ie. SUM(mySeries)+1, and call it a new function MYSUM().

I am hesitant to translate the long formula into VBA due to the potential errors that might arise and the added complexity.

Comment: Nice question, though I doubt you'll find an answer.
I think a better course would be to ask for help building the required function in VBA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you use **Excel Named Formulas**.

For instance, suppose that you need to calculate the difference between the sums of two consecutive columns (**A5:Ax - B5:Bx**) in different places in your workbook (**x** is the final row of the each column):

So you define in **A11** a name called **diff** (any name can be used) as **=Sum(A$5:A10)-Sum(B$5:B10)**, assuming that data start in row **5** until the previous row. It could be any cell, not just **A11**, but the definition changes in the same way.

Unfortunately, *Excel 2010* inserts absolute prefixes (**$**) and worksheet prefixes, so you need to erase the prefixes, but keeping the exclamation marks and erase most **$** characters.

When you move the formulas, most references are relative. So it always calculates the difference between the current column and the following, starting from the row **5** until the line before the total line.

So if you have data between **C5** and **D100** you put just **=Diff** in **C101** and it calculates **Sum(C5:C100) - Sum(D5:D100)**.

Obviously, you can use local or global names in the named formulas, like you mentioned in your question.

You can read more details in [Named Formulas](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-formulas.htm).

Answer (score 3):

I know you said no VBA, but doing as follows does **NOT** require you actually re-write your formulas, know much about VBA, nor maintain your formulas in VBA.  You can write it once and forget about it.

Create a User-Defined Function to extract the formula from a cell as a string:

```
Function GetFormula(Target As Range) As String
    GetFormula = Target.Formula
End Function
```

Create another to evaluate a string like a formula:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

If you had your master formula in sheet1!a1, then you'd put this in every cell that needs to use it:

```
=eval(getformula(sheet1!a1))
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using this method over Excel Named Formulas?

Comment: This actually defines a function, whereas "Named Formulas" just defines a reference to a result.  For example, if I want to create a function that will check if a cell is either blank or just whitespace, I'd want to call it like
`=IF(BlankOrWhitespace(A5),true,false)`.  For Named Formulas that's not possible because you're referencing the formula contents of a cell and not defining a new function

Comment: There's another problem that arises from usage of VBA. Security. Your workbook would be consindered unsafe because VBA can be abused. Your workbook would be mistaken as having virus.

Comment: @Akangkathe reason why I avoid VBA. That is so sad.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit old, but I stumbled across it looking for something else and thought I'd share a workbook I created a while back trying to accomplish this exact thing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gf5qrjj5q81tpke/Title_Case_Named_Range_Function.xlsx?dl=1

In short, you CAN create a UDF without VBA (sort of) by hijacking one of Excel's built-in formulas with a 0-length string output and coming up with a method to interpret the inserted data via Named Range string manipulation, but it is beyond inefficient to do so. YOU'VE BEEN WARNED! :)

**METHOD:**

1. In the example, I used both ***=REPT([cell reference or some text between quotes here],0)*** and ***=TEXT([cell reference or some text between quotes here],";;;")*** as the starting point to be able to have some form of user input into a built-in formula that would not produce any visible text result in the cell itself.
2. Then I created a **Named Range** that would be the equivalent of your UDF name (*TCase* is the primary example in the sheet, but there are also several other variations in there). This **Named Range** actually references a whole host of other hidden names in the workbook to extract the **FormulaText** from the cell it's used within and then applies some logic to it to produce a final output as a string. It's worth noting that this method could only return text results and not numbers (though it could return a number as text to be converted in a separate cell).
3. On its own, ***=TCase*** produces an error since there is no cell/string reference for it to interpret (in the example sheet, the error message is just a reminder of the format that needs to be followed). But, combining *TCase* with the expected 0-length string Excel formula allows it to read the input from the formula as a string and apply your logic to it. In the end, the formula/output would look something like below. Note that I inserted the text string directly in the formula below, but you'll see in the example sheet that it can also interpret a single cell reference.

   FORMULA:
   `=TCase&REPT("i want  to convert this  mIxEd  sTRing into A TITLE cAsE string!!!",0)`

   OUTPUT:

   > ```
   > I Want to Convert This Mixed String Into a Title Case String!!!
   > ```

In the end, I would *not* recommend following this method for anything other than a morbid curiosity to see what limits Excel can be pushed to. VBA is a much simpler and elegant UDF solution, but I at least had fun taking on the challenge.

***NOTE:*** If you want to see how it works in the example file a bit easier, use the **Evaluate Formula** from the Formulas ribbon and step in/out of the formula in one of the cells where I inserted an example. I hid all of the underlying Named Ranges to clean it all up after I was done, so they don't show up in the **Names Manager** unless you unhide them all.

Comment: I didn't even know one could hide names from the unzipped /xl/workbook.xml file! I tested your workbook, but all cells output the err message...

Comment: I understood the trick and was able to reproduce it in a simpler example, but I could make yours work :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a "LAMBDA function" feature in Office 365 that allows you to define a function entirely within Excel as a defined name.

No longer a need for macros and VBA. Certainly no need to "hijack" anything.

The documentation says it is available for
*Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac*, and *Excel for the web*

Please check this out:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on the [answer by @Kirk](https://superuser.com/a/1474351/375442), but I wanted to provide an MRE/MCVE of the technique he uses.

[image]

Add the following names in the Name Manager:

```
Name            Refers to
myfn            =INDIRECT(myfn.reference)+1
myfn.debug      =myfn.reference
myfn.formula    =FORMULATEXT(myfn.self)
myfn.reference  =MID(myfn.formula;myfn.textcall+1;LEN(myfn.formula)-(myfn.textcall+1)-2)
myfn.self       =INDIRECT("RC";FALSE)
myfn.textcall   =FIND("(";myfn.formula)
```

Then call the "function" with a relative ref like this:

```
=myfn&REPT(B2;0)
```

or with an absolute reference (or any other type of ref):

```
=myfn&REPT($B$2;0)
```

Note: to translate to fr-fr, one only need to replace "RC" by "LC"

Comment: This only works for a reference (a single cell, a range, or even a named range) passed as argument. To pass a string, one has to remove the `INDIRECT()` in `myfn`: `=myfn.reference&" and some appended text"` and call it like this in a cell: `=myfn&REPT("some text";0)`. If you want to pass the return value of another function as argument: `=myfn&REPT(REPT("a";3);0)` or pass a named constant (with `Refers To` set to "=1" for example): `=myfn&REPT("named_constant";0)`, the XLM `EVALUATE()` function will be required instead of `INDIRECT()` (and your file will need to be an .xlsm one)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula