# Is it possible to sum numbers separated with newlines using a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have some cells with text like

`1200
1200
1400`

And I would like to get the sum of the numbers in another cell.
I think it is impossible to do using an excel formula since there is no loop, but I may be wrong. For example, I can get a string with a formula using `=CONCATENER("=";SUBSTITUE(P25; "
";"+"))` (sorry, I use Excel in French), but I cannot evaluate it.

Comment: You can remove new lines in the formula by using =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(13),""),CHAR(10),"")

Comment: Have a look at [Excel function that evaluates a string as if it were a formula?] : http://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use one formula for this. Either use VBA or do something like

```
="="&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(13),"+"),CHAR(10),"+")
```

Then copy - paste special - paste values, then edit the cell and press enter. That's the quickest I can figure out as `INDIRECT()` won't work.