# Excel convert string equation to mathematical function

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet whereas I have a string value in one column, and I have an amount value in another column, and a balance value in yet another column.  I have a VLookup array to determine the mathematical operation in an Adjusted Balance column so I can verify the results will be correct, before I set this up in SQL to adjust balances.
Basically, spreadsheet looks like this:

```
   A             B            C               D           E        F
TransCode | TransAmount | AccountBalance | AdjBalance | Array1 | Array2 |
Debit       $20.00        -$75.00                       Debit    -
Credit      $20.00        -$55.00                       Credit    +
Credit      $15.00        -$40.00
Debit       $125.00       -$165.00
```

In my AdjBalance, I've created a formula with vlookup that looks like so:

```
=C2 & VLOOKUP(A3,E2:F3,2) & B2
```

But the results I get are -55+20.  I've tried wrapping in EVALUATE or EVAL, but Excel doesn't recognize this function.

Question is, is there a function to force the string to a mathematical equation?  I've looked and Eval is the only function I can come up with, but maybe I'm not wording my search in the right way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel function that evaluates a string as if it were a formula?](http://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula)

Comment: Try in define name give a name and in Refers to write:Evaluate(c2 & & VLOOKUP(A3,E2:F3,2) & B2)

Comment: If the limit of what you're trying to do is use + or - based on Debit or Credit, it would be a lot simpler just to use an IF.

Answer (score 0):

Define Name for example `Balance` and in Refers  to write the following

> =EVALUATE(Sheet1!C2 & VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3,Sheet1!$E$2:$F$3,2,FALSE) & Sheet1!B2)

in the cell where you want the result write = Balance and you can drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

As [fixer1234](https://superuser.com/users/364367/fixer1234) pointed out - it would be a lot more simple using an `IF`. You can just do away with columns E and F

```
=IF(A2 = "Debit",C2-B2,IF(A2 = "Credit",C2+B2,"No Transcode"))
```