# Change a function used in a formula, using the function name stored as text in a separate cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula

```
=ROUNDUP(D12/(D6-D5),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G9,reference!$C$2:$D$7,2,0),100))
```

and I want to change the `ROUNDUP` portion based on text from a separate cell (say, `F7`, where the text can be  `ROUNDDOWN` or  `ROUND` ).

I tried using the `SUBSTITUTE()` and `REPLACE()` functions. These are a couple of my attempts:

`=REPLACE("=ROUNDUP(…)",2,7,F7)`*

`=REPLACE(ROUNDUP(…),2,7,F7)`

*This version ended up creating the right formula, but it shows as text, not as a formula. I can paste it in another cell and it works. So I tried adding `*1`, in this formula but it still didn't work.

A workaround is the use of nested `IF` , but that will create far too many lines so I was hoping for another option.

Comment: What value/Function U've written in `F7` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't update a function or formula by text. Only exception is the references which can be altered by the INDIRECT function.

Comment: I added the function I want for  `F7` , @Rajesh.  @FezzikMontoya, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Actually, there's a limited capability to do this kind of thing with EVALUATE.  See https://superuser.com/a/774135/364367

Comment: @rose, Y don't U use Find & Replace by choosing Formula Option, it's easier. And if you replace the formula with Text then how it will work !!

Comment: @rose, I can suggest you MACRO(VBA) will help you to replace any part of the formula Like `Roundup` or `Iferror` or `Vlookup` with the value(function) store in cell. Just confirm are you comfortable with MACRO?

Comment: i did do macros a couple of years back, but i'd rather not at this point because people here do not know how to code and I want people to be able to edit this file. I can also do the find and replace, but I'd rather have it automatically done. thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHOOSE` and `MATCH` functions, still not optimal, but better than `IF`:

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(F7,{ROUND,ROUNDUP,ROUNDDOWN},0),ROUND(D12/(D6-D5),ROUNDUP(D12/(D6-D5),ROUNDDOWN(D12/(D6-D5))`